# How to select multiple elements in react and set a state to false

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an activeBtn function to set an activeLink class when the button is clicked. In this case, i want to remove the state of the other buttons to false when it isn't clicked. So i only have one active button at a time. i don't know how to select the elements on react. i usually use document.querySelector().classList.add() or remove to do this. how to do it on react?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Button = ({ text, data }) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  const activeBtn = () => {
    setIsActive(true)
  }
  const activeLink = 'bg-light-one text-main-color text-light-one rounded-[2rem] border-none outline-none my-[0.45rem] mx-[0.4rem] py-[0.85rem] px-[1.8rem] uppercase font-medium leading-none cursor-pointer transition duration-300';
  const normalLink = 'text-lg bg-transparent text-light-one rounded-[2rem] border-none outline-none my-[0.45rem] mx-[0.4rem] py-[0.85rem] px-[1.8rem] uppercase font-medium leading-none cursor-pointer transition duration-300';
  return (
    <button onClick={activeBtn} type='button' data-filter={data} className={isActive ? activeLink : normalLink}>
      {text}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

i tried useRef but idk how to properly use it and set the state to false

Comment: You mean, you are going to have multiple instances of the Button Component, one of each can only be active at any point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be various approaches according to the exact requirements (which are not quite clear from your question).

Here is one simple approach to have only one active button at a time.

You will need to lift the state up to a parent component that contains the buttons. This state will keep track of the active button based on some unique value or property of that button (in this example, I've used a unique `text` value). You will need to pass both the `active` state to the button as well as the setter method, in order for the buttons to be able to set the parent state and update the view with the last active button.

```
const Button = ({ text, active, setActive }) => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => setActive(text)}
      style={active === text ? { background: "green" } : { background: "red" }}
    >
      {text}
    </button>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <Button active={active} setActive={setActive} text="A" />
      <Button active={active} setActive={setActive} text="B" />
      <Button active={active} setActive={setActive} text="C" />
    </>
  );
}
```

Depending on your setup, you can also `map` over the Button elements or use the `Context API` to share the `active, setActive` state with these Button Components.

Answer (score -1):

you can use an array collect all the buttons status and by the data to drive the UI render like this:

```js
interface IButtonStatus {
        name: string
        active: boolean
        text: string
    }
    const initButtonsStatus: IButtonStatus[] = [{ name: 'btn1', active: false, text: 'button1' }, { name: 'btn2', active: false, text: 'button2' }];
    const [buttonsStatus, setButtonsStatus] = useState<IButtonStatus[]>(initButtonsStatus);

    const activeBtn = (name: string) => {
        const curButtonsStatus = [...buttonsStatus]
        curButtonsStatus.forEach(item => {
            if (item.name === name) {
                item.active = true
            } else {
                item.active = false
            }
        })
        setButtonsStatus(curButtonsStatus);
    }

    const checkStatus = (buttonName: string, buttonsStatus: IButtonStatus[]) => {
        const buttonItem = buttonsStatus.find((item: IButtonStatus) => item.name === buttonName)
        return buttonItem && buttonItem.active ? "active" : "normal"
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {
                buttonsStatus.map((item: IButtonStatus) => {
                    return <button key={item.name}
                        onClick={() => activeBtn(item.name)}
                        className={checkStatus(item.name, buttonsStatus)}>{item.text}</button>
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
```

I use `TypeScript`, you can remove the type declarations.

Comment: As all the TS types have :any (which defeats the purpose of using a strictly typed language) you can remove them to make the code more readable. Also, the 2nd button seems to have data related to the first button (btn1 on the click handler, button1 as text). Also, inside the activeBtn function you are directly mutating the state which is considered a practice to be avoided in React. You are returning the same state object which results in the Component NOT triggering a re-render. Please double check and test that your code works before posting an answer, as it will cost time and confusion.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis yes, i am careless, i have edit my answer ,i do not think your answer is a good result so i give my answer, beause data drive render is the core idea in react, but your answer do not get this key point